# Updating a dictionary with a class function

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a CRM in Python as a final project to a course. 
And I create a dictionary to use like a "database" form my CRM.

First, I tryed update the dict outside a class:

```
index_db = {}

index_db[len(index_db)] = {'name_first': 'Johnny', 'name_last': 'Quest', 'email': 'jquest@cartoonville.com', 'phone': '1 365 999999999'}
index_db[len(index_db)] = {'name_first': 'Scooby', 'name_last': 'Doo', 'email': 'sdoo@cartoonville.com', 'phone': '1 365 888888888'}
index_db[len(index_db)] = {'name_first': 'Homer', 'name_last': 'Simpson', 'email': 'hsimpson@cartoonville.com', 'phone': '1 365 777777777'}
```

And it's return:

```
{
    0: {
        'name_first': 'Johnny',
        'name_last': 'Quest',
        'email': 'jquest@cartoonville.com',
        'phone': '1 365 999999999'
    },
    1: {
        'name_first': 'Scooby',
        'name_last': 'Doo',
        'email': 'sdoo@cartoonville.com',
        'phone': '1 365 888888888'
    },
    2: {
        'name_first': 'Homer',
        'name_last': 'Simpson',
        'email': 'hsimpson@cartoonville.com',
        'phone': '1 365 777777777'
    }
}
```

It's look great, so I created a class:

```
class Consumer(object):
    index_db = {}
    args = {'name_first': None, 'name_last': None, 'email': None, 'phone': None}

    def __set__(self, var, val):
        self.args[var] = val

    def __insert__(self):
        self.index_db[len(self.index_db)] = self.args
```

And insert three consumers:

```
consumer = Consumer()

consumer.__set__('name_first', 'Johnny')
consumer.__set__('name_last', 'Bravo')
consumer.__set__('email', 'jbravo@cartoonville.com')
consumer.__set__('phone', '1 353 30316541')
consumer.__insert__()

consumer.__set__('name_first', 'Dexter')
consumer.__set__('name_last', 'Scientist')
consumer.__set__('email', 'dscientist@cartoonville.com')
consumer.__set__('phone', '1 353 33256001')
consumer.__insert__()

consumer.__set__('name_first', 'Barney')
consumer.__set__('name_last', 'Gumble')
consumer.__set__('email', 'bgumble@cartoonville.com')
consumer.__set__('phone', '1 353 555961533')
consumer.__insert__()
```

And it's return:

```
{
    0: {
        'email': 'bgumble@cartoonville.com',
        'name_first': 'Barney',
        'name_last': 'Gumble',
        'phone': '1 353 555961533'},
    1: {
        'email': 'bgumble@cartoonville.com',
        'name_first': 'Barney',
        'name_last': 'Gumble',
        'phone': '1 353 555961533'},
    2: {
        'email': 'bgumble@cartoonville.com',
        'name_first': 'Barney',
        'name_last': 'Gumble',
        'phone': '1 353 555961533'
    }
}
```

Oh God, why does not this work?

Comment: Its because you keep overwriting elements within the same dictionary, `args`, which you create once as a class member.

Comment: All  your `Consumer` objects share a single dictionary, whenever you change one of them, you change all of them.  Define an `__init__` method.  that sets up instance variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty fix is this:

```
import copy
class Consumer(object):
    index_db = {}
    args = {'name_first': None, 'name_last': None, 'email': None, 'phone': None}

    def __set__(self, var, val):
        self.args[var] = val

    def __insert__(self):
        self.index_db[len(self.index_db)] = self.args
        Consumer.args = copy.deepcopy(self.args)
```

The `deepcopy` creates a new dictionary for you.

Really, you need a better interface to your class.

And as @Hai Vu says: What's with the **dunder** methods?

This might be better. And yes, I know it needs more lines to use:

```
class Consumer(object):
    index_db = {}

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):
        cls.args = {'name_first': None, 'name_last': None, 'email': None, 'phone': None}

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, var, val):
        cls.args[var] = val

    @classmethod
    def insert(cls):
        cls.index_db[len(cls.index_db)] = cls.args

consumer = Consumer

consumer.reset()
consumer.set('name_first', 'Johnny')
consumer.set('name_last', 'Bravo')
consumer.set('email', 'jbravo@cartoonville.com')
consumer.set('phone', '1 353 30316541')
consumer.insert()
```

Note that since `index_db` is a member of the class, the whole thing might as well be at the class level, so that's what's with the `@classmethod` s.

Answer (score 1):

As @quamrana pointed out, your code keep reusing the same copy of `self.args`. Another quick-and-dirty fix is to reset `self.args` right after insert:

```
    def __insert__(self):
        self.index_db[len(self.index_db)] = self.args
        self.args = {'name_first': None, 'name_last': None, 'email': None, 'phone': None}
```

The last line creates a new dictionary, ready to be populated.

By the way, what's with the **dunder** (double underscores)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing things.  This moves everything to the `__init__` method. Now the `Consumer` has an attribute `index` that it updates whenever a new `Consumer` is created.

```
class Consumer(dict):
  index={}
  _count=0
  def __init__(self, first=None, last=None, email=None, phone=None):
    super().__init__(name_first=first, name_last=last, email=email, phone=phone)
    Consumer.index[Consumer._count] = self
    Consumer._count += 1
```

now after

```
Consumer('Johnny', 'Bravo', 'jbravo@cartoonville.com', '1 353 30316541')
Consumer('Dexter', 'Scientist', 'dscientist@cartoonville.com', '1 353 33256001')
Consumer('Barney', 'Gumble', 'bgumble@cartoonville.com', '1 353 555961533')
```

`Consumer.index` will be equal to

```
{0: {'email': 'jbravo@cartoonville.com',
     'name_first': 'Johnny',
     'name_last': 'Bravo',
     'phone': '1 353 30316541'},
 1: {'email': 'dscientist@cartoonville.com',
     'name_first': 'Dexter',
     'name_last': 'Scientist',
     'phone': '1 353 33256001'},
 2: {'email': 'bgumble@cartoonville.com',
     'name_first': 'Barney',
     'name_last': 'Gumble',
     'phone': '1 353 555961533'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

I follow the @patrick-haugh tip, and created a **init** who clear my dictionary, and call the **init** again after insert a consumer.

Like this:

```
class Consumer(object):
  index_db = {}

  def __init__(self):
    Consumer.args = {'name_first': None, 'name_last': None, 'email': None, 'phone': None}

  def __set__(self, var, val):
    self.args[var] = val

  def __insert__(self):
    self.index_db[len(self.index_db)] = self.args
    self.__init__()
```

@quamrana thanks for the dirty and the cool solution! I will improve the interface of my classes ;)

@hai-vu: The dunder is because I can't use the name set(), so i put the double underscores in all defs to create a ugly default, kkk.

And again, thanks everyone!